# Core Data - why fetch request returns nil?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have code, which fetches core data

```
    var appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "QuestionDB")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    if let results = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
```

it returns array of `AnyObject`

I need it to return array of objects with type of `[Question]`

when i cast

```
    var appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "QuestionDB")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    if let results = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as? [Question] {
        println("This is result of loadFromDb \(results)")
    }
```

it returns nil

How can i fix it ?

Comment: check class name in data model inspector of Entity in data model.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you found solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check class name in data model inspector of Entity in data model by

select your app's `.xcdatamodeld` -> `select Entity` and in `data model inspector`

[image]

Comment: yes, it has entity name of QuestionDB and class MillionaireIII.QuestionDB (MillionaireIII - name of app)

Comment: check if you have any error in fetch by `var error : NSError? = nil` and `managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)`

Comment: I checked, and it says - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. But when I fetch without casting it prints out all objects from DB without any error

Comment: then try using AnyObject and `for result in results! as [Question] {}`

Comment: Thank you! I'd forgotten to set the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"QuestionDB")

    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        return results  as! [QuestionDB]
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
```

If your class name is `Question` you have to set it in the model inspector.

Comment: compiler returns error with [QuestionDB] is not convertible to "()"